# Multiple sorting conditions of a WPF combobox/listbox or CollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I haven't been able to find this as a previous request by searching, which is strange. I am simply trying to apply multiple sort conditions to a collection view that is bound to a comboBox.

I have tried this:

```
cmbRptCur.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Length", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
cmbRptCur.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

But only the first sorting condition is applied. It is a list of strings, which I would like to be sorted first by the length of the string, ascending, and within that, alphabetically ascending. Ideally I would like to know how to do both ways so I can make the best choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as an example:

```
var variable = ListSortDirection.Orderby(c => c.Length).ThenBy(n => n.Content)
```

Or something like that.

Or this:

```
var variable = (from c in ListSortDirections
         orderby c.Length, c.Content
         select row).ToList();
```

Just as an example.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to try the LINQ route even though there should be another way. I needed to use .Cast<string>() to get it in a queryable format, and it works fine. I'd still like to know how to do it directly on the combobox, and by not having to resort to LINQ.

i.e.

(from c in ListCollectionView.Cast<string>() orderby c.Length, c select c).ToList());